# Sencha: How to generate all-classes file

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

Morning,

My production build seems to be missing getOrientation function. 
It seems that sencha-touch-all.js is not being copied into the build folder.

After doing much forum reading, etc, I have discovered that I actually need to use Cmd to create an all-classes.js file.

According to http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/guide/building, the following command should do the job:

`sencha create jsb -a index.html -p app.jsb3`

When I run this in command from within the root of my app (where index.html lives), I get the following error:

> [ERR] Unknown command: "create"

I have tried using commands `generate` or `build` instead of `create` but they do not work either.

So, why does it not recognise that command?

When I run the command from within my SenchaSDKTools folder, but use the full path/to/app,
it seems to accept the command, but does not create a file.

I have sencha touch 2.2.1 and Cmd 3.1.2.342

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

It was working fine from within the SenchaSDKtools folder. I hadn't told it the right place to  create the file.

Answer (score 2):

In order for you to use `sencha create jsb` command, you have to:

1. Install Sencha SDK Tools

   Mac     - http://cdn.sencha.io/sdk-tools/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3-osx.app.zip 
   Windows - http://cdn.sencha.io/sdk-tools/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3-windows.exe
2. Open terminal and change directory to where the Sencha SDK is installed.

   `cd /Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3/`
3. Generate a JSB3 file by executing the ff. command:

   `/sencha create jsb -a index.html -p app.jsb3`

   wherein:

   -a (required) The location of the HTML file containing the scripts you want to include
   -p (required) The location where the output .jsb3 file should be created

   This scans your index.html file for all framework and application files that are actually used by the app, and then creates a **JSB** file called app.jsb3.